# " Object to int" operator causes NullReferenceException in c#

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I have a problem with converting object to integer. I get NullReferenceException every time i run my code. Is there any way to omit it ? The problem is about "public static implicit operator int".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Item
    {
        int number;

        public Item(int number1)
        {
            number = number1;
        }

        public static implicit operator int (Item item)
        // convert item to int
        {

            return item.number;
        }
        public static implicit operator Item(int number)
        // convert int to item
        {
            return new Item(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your calling code where you get the exception

Comment: Code is perfectly ok. I checked it.

Comment: Can't reproduce, working fine for me. You did not include the relevant code.

Comment: This is super easy to reproduce. If your Item object is null then trying to cast it to an int will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Item` where you implicitly cast to an `int` is `null`, for example:

```
Item item = null;
int a = item; //Will call the implicit operator with null
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

The middle line will call the implicit operator with `null` which will cause it to look for `item.number` where `item` is null and will throw a `NullReferenceException` as if you would write the following:

```
Item item = null;
int a = Item.operator_int(item);
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

You should change your operator to set a default value, for example:

```
public static implicit operator int (Item item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        return default(int); //0
    }
    return item.number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We'd need to see the code where you're converting this object to an integer, but this sort of thing can happen if your calling code looks like this:

```
Item item = null;
int i = item;
```

The compiler will turn that into something roughly equivalent to this (provided this was syntactically valid):

```
Item item = null;
int i = Item.operator_int( item );
```

Since `item` is null, that's what gets passed into your operator and when you try to get the `number` field from `item` (which is null), it'll throw a NullReferenceException.  You need to check if `item` is null in your operator.